# Import/Export a FIT file, Fitness file created by Garmin GPS's and others

Tags: export, import

A FIT file is a binary replacement for GPX and TCX text files containing GPS and fitness data (heart monitors, etc.).  Mathematica reads GPX and TCX files and represents them as XML. I would like to have the same for FIT files.

Comment: Please provide a specification for the file format, otherwise it is a bit much to expect someone to write the format converter...

Comment: I am looking into the same topic.
I just recently found:
https://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit
From what I understand it contains information/code that enables you to build your own .fit reader/writer. Some knowledge in in C/C++/C#/Java is probably needed. I have not yet pursued this any further. /RB

Comment: I asked WRI about this earlier in the year but I don't recall if I heard back from them. There is a [`"FITS"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/FITS.html) file-type that can have the _.fit_ file extension.  I'm guessing this might be creating some backward compatibility issues with implementing the fitness data file-type since it has the same _.fit_ file extension. It may even be using the same file specification. I never thought to try it. Give it a go and see if it imports with `"FITS"`.

Comment: I tried in Mathematica 13.2.1 and it says "Import::infer: Cannot infer format of file 10545049211_ACTIVITY.fit" when I try without specifying the format. When using `"FITS"` format, it says "Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as FITS format."